# Get type parameter from a generic struct using reflection

Tags: go, generics, reflection

Imagine I have the following struct:

```
type MyGeneric[T string | int] struct {
}
```

I want to check whether the generic used to instantiate that struct was a string or a int when creating a new MyGeneric.

```
myGenericString := MyGeneric[string]{}
myGenericString.canHandle("hello") -> should return true
myGenericString.canHandle(8) -> should return false

func (mG MyGeneric[T]) canHandle(value any) bool {
    // how to get what T is the same type as value
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For normal values, just instantiate the `T` directly to get its value and `reflect.TypeOf()` it. But we can declare a `[0]T` and take its element type instead, because:

- `[0]T` takes 0 memory while `T` may be as large as `T`, which would waste a lot of stack and heap <sup>1</sup> if `T` is something like `[4096]int`.
- A raw `T` does not work with interface types. `reflect.TypeOf()` on a nil interface value (whether empty interface or not) will return `reflect.Type(nil)`, of which subsequent uses will cause panic.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyGeneric[T any] struct {
}

func (mG MyGeneric[T]) canHandle(value any) bool {
    var zero [0]T
    tt := reflect.TypeOf(zero).Elem()
    vt := reflect.TypeOf(value)

    fmt.Printf("-> %v covers %v\n", tt, vt)
    return vt.AssignableTo(tt)
}

type empty struct{}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", MyGeneric[string]{}.canHandle(""))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", MyGeneric[any]{}.canHandle(""))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", MyGeneric[string]{}.canHandle(1))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", MyGeneric[MyGeneric[struct{}]]{}.canHandle(MyGeneric[struct{}]{}))
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", MyGeneric[MyGeneric[struct{}]]{}.canHandle(MyGeneric[empty]{}))
}
```

Output:

```
-> string covers string
true
-> interface {} covers string
true
-> string covers int
false
-> main.MyGeneric[struct {}] covers main.MyGeneric[struct {}]
true
-> main.MyGeneric[struct {}] covers main.MyGeneric[main.empty]
false
```

<sup>1</sup> Not sure if it can be optimized out or whether it allocates on heap or stack or both, because it is passed into `reflect.TypeOf` after upcasting to an `interface{}`.

Comment: note that this solution works unless `T` is instantiated with interfaces.

Comment: @blackgreen it works if you use the `[0]T` method.

Comment: Updated the answer to prioritize the `[0]T` instead of `T`.

Answer (score 5):

It hasn't been implemented yet. There is an [open proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/54393) about adding the necessary methods to `reflect.Type`.

The current workaround as of Go 1.19 is to parse the string obtained from `TypeOf`. Something like this:

```
var r = regexp.MustCompile("[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9_]+\\[(.*)\\]")

func (mG MyGeneric[T]) typeParam(value any) {
    tname := reflect.TypeOf(mG).String() // this is `main.MyGeneric[string]`
    match := r.FindStringSubmatch(tname)
    fmt.Println(match[1]) // string
}
```

This if the goal is just to obtain the name of the type parameter. It's not great, as it depends on the type's string representation. On the bright side, it doesn't force you to think about what happens if you instantiate `T` with interfaces.

If you need to do further computations with the type of `T`, e.g. compare it to other types etc. [@SOFe’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73932292/4108803) provides a solution that doesn’t depend on arbitrary string representations.

However watch out for `T` instantiated with interfaces: see also [In Golang, how to compare interface as generics type to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000242/in-golang-how-to-compare-interface-as-generics-type-to-nil)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to add a placeHolder field to your struct, that can be used to get its type via type switch to avoid reflect:

```
type MyGeneric[T string | int] struct {
  placeHolder T
}

func (mG MyGeneric[T]) canHandle(value any) bool {
    switch t1 := any(p.placeHolder).(type) {
    case any:
        switch t2 := value.(type) {
        case any:
            return t1 == t2
        }
    }
    return false
}
```