# In Golang, how to compare interface as generics type to nil?

Tags: go, generics

I need a linked node to hold some different interface types, so I made it with generics, but the generics type `any` can't be compared to nil, it shows error as in the comment:

```golang
package main

type myInterface interface {
}
type node[T any] struct {
    next *node[T]
    leaf T
}

func (n *node[T]) GetFirstNodeHasLeaf() *node[T] {
    if n.leaf != nil { // <---- error here: cannot compare n.leaf != nil (mismatched types T and untyped nil)
        return n
    }

    if n.next == nil {
        return nil
    } else {
        return n.next.GetFirstNodeHasLeaf()
    }
}

func main() {
    var n = &node[myInterface]{}
    // fill n with lots of nodes
    n.GetFirstNodeHasLeaf() // get the first node that has (leaf != nil)
}
```

I also tried to compare with a default value

```golang
    var nilT T
    if n.leaf != nilT { // <-- same problem
```

And restrict the node type as

```golang
type node[T myInterface] struct {
```

Same error, how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using an interface to instantiate a generic type like `node` is probably a conceptual flaw. So let's see the general cases first, and the interface case at the end.

#### Using `comparable` and `T`

If you want to use equality operators like `==` and `!=` with values of type parameter type, the constraint must be `comparable`.

```
type node[T comparable] struct {
    next *node[T]
    leaf T
}
```

but then you're not going to test against `nil`, you would test against `T`'s zero value, which, depending on what you instantiate it with, could be something other than `nil`.

In that case you would declare a variable of type `T` for its zero value:

```
var zero T
if n.leaf != zero {
    return n
}
```

However interface types don't implement `comparable`.

#### Using `any` and `*T`

As an alternative, you can keep the constraint `any` and declare the field `leaf` as a pointer to `T`. That supports equality operators, because `leaf` type isn't a type parameter anymore, it's a pointer:

```
type node[T any] struct {
    next *node[T]
    leaf *T
}

func (n *node[T]) GetFirstNodeHasLeaf() *node[T] {
    if n.leaf != nil { // ok, leaf is a pointer type
        return n
    }
...
}
```

#### Using `any` and `T`

With the constraint `any`, `T` doesn't support the equality operators; you could instantiate `node` with literally any type, including those that aren't comparable.

As long as the field isn't a pointer, you can only use reflection to check for the zero value (`nil` for pointer types`):

```
if !reflect.ValueOf(n.leaf).IsZero() {
    return n
}
```

Finally, consider that the above code doesn't work if `T` is an interface type. What is tested is the dynamic value boxed in the interface. If `T` really must be an interface, test for the zero value with:

```
// leaf is an interface type
if !reflect.ValueOf(&n.leaf).Elem().IsZero() {
    return n
}
```